# Why does SoapClient using WSDL in document/literal style return array with extra key element?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

We are in the process of converting a RPC/encoded webservice to document/literal/wrapped.
The WSDL (using nusoap) is already rewritten to use the new format.

I use PHP SoapClient like this:

```
new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array(
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace' => true,
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
));
```

The relevant WSDL parts looks like this, (should be following the WS-I Basic Profile):

```
<xsd:complexType name="messages">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="item" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="some_functionResponseType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="return" type="tns:messages" form="unqualified"/>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

<message name="some_functionResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:some_functionResponseType"/>
</message>

<operation name="some_function">
    <input message="tns:some_functionRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:some_functionResponse"/>
</operation>
```

When I submit my request, the XML response is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <some_functionResponse xmlns="urn:toets_nl_wsdl">
      <messages xmlns="">
        <item>foo</item>
        <item>bar</item>
      </messages>
    </some_functionResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When I dump the result object in PHP, it looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [messages] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => Array             // <-- here
                (
                    [0] => foo
                    [1] => bar
                )

        )

)
```

Why is there an extra element "item" in the result tree? This wasn't there when we were still using RPC/encoded.

Is there a way to remove that element when processing the response?

Comment: Can you post the WSDL and schema?  What did it look like when you were still using RPC/encoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WSDL clearly states that there is an item with unlimited number of occurrences, that contains strings (also known as an array). So PHP just presents to you the structure as described in the WSDL, and as returned by the server.

I cannot see that there is anything wrong. Don't expect Soap to be the same as RPC just because it does the same. If you don't want that item element there, change the WSDL and the service - but this might be more difficult than to fit your PHP client code to the new data structure.

You even used SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, which is a good thing to avoid checking if the element really was an array or not.

Comment: The WSDL arrays are build according to the WS-I specification, which I think is the authorative source here? (http://ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.2-2010-11-09.html#soapenc_Array). I see PHP just parses this simply literally, and I assumed it could be "smarter" when detecting this array constructions. Do other (and maybe more mature) SOAP Clients (in other languages) handle this the same way?

Comment: Other languages offer different variable structures that might be able to cover this case better, but PHP can only offer either arrays or objects - and the SoapClient itself also has to do the mapping of such data structures back and forth to XML. And doing "smart" optimization would be the wrong thing - that's why you have SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, which disables exactly this "smart" behaviour on a different level.

Comment: Sven, did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure that it's not specified in the WSDL definition somewhere? I'm sure that the extra element is not added by the server for fun :)

Or perhaps it's a consequence of the encoding style of the document.

The **item** element is very common in SAP Webservices (which I use regularly) when returning content of an array type but, like I wrote above, it's clearly specified in the WSDL.

You may also find that when the array has only one element **item** will not be an array so take care of that in your code using

```
if(!is_array($messages->item)) {
    $messages->item = array($messages->item);
}
```

Comment: When there is only one item, PHP Soap has an option SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS to prevent the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Yes, the "item" name is in the WSDL (and also in the message). And maybe this is just what you get when you want to use arrays in document/literal, but I hope I'm just missing something.

Comment: I never noticed SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS! Thanks for that. I always thought it was the server that determined it :)